# Declining to interview with a company due to poor work-life balance culture. Should I let the recruiter know why declined?

Tags: professionalism, applications, rejection

A local employer contacted me on LinkedIn, but through my interactions with their employees, I learned that they have a poor work-life balance culture where employees are expected to work long hours. Glassdoor reviews also support this.

It is important to me to have my usual hours be 40 (or even a little less), so I have deliberately not applied to this company even though they have openings that are an excellent match for my skillset.

Should I reply?  If so, should I give a generic rejection? or should I explain I am not interested due to their poor work-life balance culture?

Comment: Do you have anything to gain by telling them this?

Comment: Perhaps others have something to gain, I don't think that should be the only consideration.

Comment: I think jcmack and Erik articulated well when this would be beneficial - with a personal recruiter or with another person who ended up making repeated contact. Neither case applies here, and it is helpful to have it spelled out that way.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell the recruiter preemptively the exact reason for not pursuing if you feel compelled to or if the recruiter reaches back out and ask you. I would personally chose to not to give this information preemptively, but may do so, if they asked me for feedback.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an in-house recruiter, there is not an awful lot to gain by telling them the reasons you are declining. They'll likely not contact you again anyway and they're not going to be passing on jobs at other companies to you, so it's probably a waste of time to tell them.

If you're dealing with a personal recruiter who is helping you look for work, you should tell them, because they need to know your preferences so they can send the right kind of jobs to you. In this case, you can still give a general reason to the company itself, but the recruiter will know to skip these types of companies in the future.